# Ruby on Rails Require Input dependent on dropdown value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

I have a select box in a ruby on rails site.  When this box has a particular value selected, I have a script that will dynamically show or hide another text field to enter additional information. Is it possible to **require** that additional text field only if that particular value (or index) has been selected?  I don't want it to be required for any other indexes in that dropdown.  Here's the code that I currently have to control the hiding/showing.

**From View**

```
<div class="field">
  <%= f.input :response_time, collection: [['Non Emergency', 'Non Emergency'],
      ...., ['Immediate', 'Immediate']], label: false, :prompt => "Select
      Response Time", :input_html => {:onchange => "showDiv(this)"},
      :wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline' } %> 
  <span class="text-error">*</span>
</div>

<div id="hidediv" style="display:none;">
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.input :imm_reason, as: :text, input_html: { rows: "6", class: 'span6',
    title: 'Immediate Reason' }, placeholder: 'If response time is
    Immediate, please indicate reason...', label: false, 
    :wrapper_html => { :style => 'display: inline' } %>
</div></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showDiv(obj)
{
  var boxval = obj[obj.selectedIndex].value;
  if(boxval == 'Immediate')
  {
      document.getElementById('hidediv').style.display = 'block';
  }
  else
  {
      document.getElementById('hidediv').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript you can do a frontend validation (not a replacement for server-side validation) requiring the `:imm_reason` input to have content depending on the value of the the `:response_time` dropdown. You can also use the html5 `required` attribute. Both these approaches, since they're client-side, rely on browser support and won't work in every browser.

Since this question is tagged Rails, I think you're looking for help on how to enforce the validation server-side. That's smart. You should always do server-side validations, even if you also validate in the frontend.

In your model, you want something like the following:

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :imm_reason, :if => :immediate_response_time?

  def immediate_response_time?
    response_time == 'Immediate'
  end
end
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: If I already have validates_presence_of :location, :description, :response_time in the model, would those only be validated upon that if rule as well?

Comment: Behavior for them would stay the same. They would always be validated. They would only be conditionally validated if you added a guard to their validations too (by "guard" I mean appending an `:if` or `:unless` conditional to the validation)

Comment: This worked fine, thank you.  One thing to note, I did have to add a js event for the page load to ensure that the reason box displayed when it took the user back for a bad entry.  Otherwise, they had to change the selection and then change it back.

Comment: good point. If you wanted you could also have the view show (or hide) the `:imm_reason` on page load using erb. Many ways to skin the cat ;)